# How to substring a string from the end of the string

Tags: c#, string, winforms, substring, substr

I want to cut the end of the sring:

Input string:

```
/O=Shore Tel/OU=CANDY/cn=Recipients/cn=PAgricola
/O=Shore Tel/OU=CANDY/cn=Recipients/cn=YAchmanov
/o=Shore Tel/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=Mukul Agrawal2f2
/o=Shore Tel/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=Nick Aiello816
```

Output string:

```
/O=Shore Tel/OU=CANDY/cn=Recipients
/O=Shore Tel/OU=CANDY/cn=Recipients
/o=Shore Tel/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients
/o=Shore Tel/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients
```

Could you give me a suggestions?

Comment: Search about String.Split, String.LastIndexOf, String.Substring. This is all you need to know to solve the puzzle.

Comment: my problem and the topic are different. I saw it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can find the last index of `"/cn="`, and substring from zero to that position:

```
int pos = str.LastIndexOf("/cn=");
if (pos > 0) {
    str = str.Substring(0, pos);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/mEj7Pi)

Answer (score 0):

It just one line in LINQ

```
string input = @"/O=Shore Tel/OU=CANDY/cn=Recipients/cn=PAgricola
                 /O=Shore Tel/OU=CANDY/cn=Recipients/cn=YAchmanov
                 /o=Shore Tel/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=Mukul Agrawal2f2
                 /o=Shore Tel/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=Nick Aiello816";

var result = string.Join("\n", input.Split('\n')
                                    .Select(x => x.Substring(0, x.LastIndexOf('/')))
                                    .ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

For readability I have used the verbatim @ character and aligned the substrings, but this introduces some unwanted whitespaces. It is not clear how your input string is formatted, but the key point here is the line that sets the result variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string s = "/O=Shore Tel/OU=CANDY/cn=Recipients/cn=PAgricola";
    s=s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("s/cn="));
```

Comment: This will cut the string at the first occurence of /cn= and it is not what has been asked.

Comment: @ steve : see the updates